# Show that the equation of the form $x^2$$-$$y^3$$=$$1$ has solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the equation of the form $x^2$$-$$y^3$$=$$1$ has solutions $x$ and $y$ $\in$  $\mathbb{  Z }$

Comment: What's Portuguese for "I know you speak English"?

Comment: @Joseph: It's ''Eu sei que você fala Inglês''.

Answer (score 6):

$$0^2-(-1)^3=(-1)^2-0^3=1^2-0^3=3^2-2^3=(-3)^2-2^3=1$$

It turns out these are all possible solutions.

Comment: Easy enough to cite the Catalan conjecture to prove that those are all. There is probably a more elementary solution though.